# Email myself on a particular day of the week

Tags: calendar

I want to be able to set up a system to email me on a certain day of the week for the next n weeks. I tried to use Google calendar, but it only let's me set the notification for the day before, not the day of, so I then have incorrect info in my calendar. Is there a simple app that will do this?

Comment: You can change the default notification time in Google Calendar under `Settings -> Calendars -> Edit Notifications`. [Here's what you'll see](http://i.imgur.com/SwL3cxC.png)

Comment: But there's no 0 days before option

Comment: You can input `0` in the field and it will save, but I haven't tested if the notification works, doesn't it?

Comment: Speaking of "simple app": Android? iOS? Web-App? Or would even a Cron job on Linux suffice ("shell app" ;) ?

Comment: Webapp send easiest

Comment: Did you tried ifttt? It supports sending email on a specific time of a day on a specific week of day (have some more options actually). It also has a web, ios and android app.                                                                        Btw, you didnt provide what will be in email would change answers you get.